# Review Queue statistics

Tags: discussion, review

Is there any way that someone can determine the stats for the review queues and how they compare to other sites on the Stack Exchange network? I was wondering about some of the following stats.

1. Amount of items in the queue
2. Amount of items in the queue completed
3. Amount of items that age out of the queue
4. Average time that an item spends in the queue (either to completion or age out)
5. How the site compares for the stats against other sites

I remember seeing something in the past that gave some information on how long items where in the queues but I am unable to find it again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to get those per site statistics. The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/439518) gives you the asked stats for a site.

```sql
select rtt.name
     , sum( case 
            when rt.reviewtaskstateid = 1 then 1
            else 0
            end ) as [Active]
     , sum( case 
            when rt.reviewtaskstateid = 2 then 1
            else 0
            end ) as [Completed]
     , sum( case 
            when rt.reviewtaskstateid = 3 then 1
            else 0
            end ) as [Invalidated]
     , min(datediff(hh, creationdate, deletiondate)) as [Minhours]
     , Max(datediff(hh, creationdate, deletiondate)) as [Maxhours]
     , avg(datediff(hh, creationdate, deletiondate)) as [Avghours]
from reviewtasks rt
inner join reviewtasktypes rtt on rtt.id = rt.reviewtasktypeid
group by rtt.name
```

I'm not sure how you think comparing these against other sites will be useful so I didn't provide an instant solution for that. You can run this query against other sites at will and then make the comparison yourself.

Do know that the SEDE databases are refreshed once per week, on Sunday around 03:00 UTC. At the day of posting for Stack Overflow the results showed this:

[image: results of review queues on Stack Overflow]

Comment: I think being able to compare the stats on against different sites can be useful when members of a beta site are discussing graduation. Being able to see where a site falls on the list and knowing it will most likely drop with the increased reputation levels for privileges can be useful. Especially if the site is one of the slower ones to start of.

Comment: When I saw this question having one answer in the list, I kind of knew it had to be rene. Thanks a lot from all of us.